# Date-based primary key instead of auto increment integer

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a database with a field name ID and is serving as a primary key. Now i want it to be auto incremented on every new record entry, but on the basis of the date.
For ex. for date 5/7/2011, i want my value as, 001050711, 002050711....001050811, 002050811....(000-MM-dd-yy). I want to do it in Sql Server, but not in my c# programming. How to do it?

Comment: Triggers would be best bet for such kind a scenario. But what is the dire need for having the primary key this way? What if there are more than 1000 insertions on a given day?

Comment: It would be better to just add a `inserted_at` date field that has a default of `NOW()`.  Your idea is a kludge and will cause a future programmer to grimace (might be you).

Comment: Agreed. I would strongly recommend using a standard identity field as the primary key, then storing the date and instance number as separate fields.

Comment: taken all your words........going with c# programming to generate it.

Comment: You mean ignoring the core advice. This is an antipattern you follow. Either veryu nexperienced, or the type that gets people fired.

Comment: @TomTom: Two antipatterns. The second one is "There will always be only one application."

Comment: from outside it may look a bit weird to some, but better to come out of glider and step on ground. it is not necessary to consider ur idea as great an effective always. and if it is, they must be owners of apple or google

Comment: There is a difference between trying outsomething new and violating what 20 years of experienced programmers found out to be a trap for inexperienced people. Google and Apple are not run by inexperienced people. You make a beginner mistake.

Comment: I am dubious this is a "companies mistake". Your question says "I created...", "my value...". But when knowledgeable, helpful people point out problems you say their ideas are "not necessary" and say your client is "forcing" it. Really? Is it possible you do not understand everything about the system you are working on? That you have misunderstood or misrepresented something about your client? You have already misrepresented the commenters as saying "going with C# programming". That is not what they are saying. Perhaps the client is saying something different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a peculiar Primary Key choice. There could also be strong potential for duplicate key values.

My advice, don't do it this way just because you can.

Perhaps you can share the business object/process it is that you are wanting to model?

Comment: @user815600: In my opinion if a client is "forcing" you to implement a specific solution against better advice, then maybe their not the type of client you want to work with. As a Consultant, it's your responsibility to deliver the most suitable solution and to be able to communicate to the client why your chosen implementation method is the best way forward for them. Best of luck with your project.